# Discord bot is not responding

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am using this code, but my Discord bot is offline and is not responding. I have given it the required permissions, but it is still not responding.

Can you have a look? I have removed the tokens for privacy reasons, but I am obviously using them when running the file so please have a look at the code and let me know how I can make this work?

```js
const NLPCloudClient = require('nlpcloud');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

// Load NLP Cloud token and Discord Bot token.
const nlpcloudToken = '';
if (nlpcloudToken == null) {
    console.error('No NLP Cloud token received');
    process.exit();
}
const discordBotToken = '';
if (discordBotToken == null) {
    console.error('No Discord bot token received');
    process.exit();
}

// Initialize the NLP Cloud and Discord clients.
const nlpCloudClient = new NLPCloudClient('fast-gpt-j', nlpcloudToken, true)
const discordClient = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers] });

let history = [];

discordClient.on("messageCreate", function(message) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    (async () => {
        // Send request to NLP Cloud.
        const response = await nlpCloudClient.chatbot(`${message.content}`, history);

        // Send response to Discord bot.
        message.reply(`${response.data['response']}`);

        // Add the request and response to the chat history.
        history.push({'input':`${message.content}`,'response':`${response.data['response']}`});
        
    })();
});
```

Your help is much appreciated. I have tried giving it all the permissions and adding it to the server.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you only check if the Discord token is provided, but you forgot to login using your token. In this case, you have to add this line of code as well:

```js
discordClient.login(discordBotToken)
```

This will make make a connection to the Discord API endpoints for bots. After the connection is successful and the token has been verified by Discord, the bot will appear online and you'll be able to use the events.

On this line, you are checking if the token has been provided in the `discordBotToken` variable, so you have to use `else` to make the bot login *if* a token is provided, like so:

```js
const NLPCloudClient = require('nlpcloud');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

// Load NLP Cloud token and Discord Bot token.
const nlpcloudToken = '';
if (nlpcloudToken == null) {
    console.error('No NLP Cloud token received');
    process.exit();
}

// Initialize the NLP Cloud and Discord clients.
const nlpCloudClient = new NLPCloudClient('fast-gpt-j', nlpcloudToken, true)
const discordClient = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers] });

// Set Discord token and check if provided, then login
const discordBotToken = '';
if (discordBotToken == null) {
    console.error('No Discord bot token received');
    process.exit();
} else {
    discordClient.login(discordBotToken);
}

let history = [];

discordClient.on("debug", console.debug); // For debugging Discord endpoint purposes only
discordClient.once("ready", () => console.log(`Signed in as ${discordClient.user.tag}`));
discordClient.on("messageCreate", function(message) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    (async () => {
        // Send request to NLP Cloud.
        const response = await nlpCloudClient.chatbot(`${message.content}`, history);

        // Send response to Discord bot.
        message.reply(`${response.data['response']}`);

        // Add the request and response to the chat history.
        history.push({'input':`${message.content}`,'response':`${response.data['response']}`});
        
    })();
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me which part exactly in the code should i add this?

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. Unfortunately I get this error now. ReferenceError: Cannot access 'discordClient' before initialization

Comment: @FardanQureshi Move the `if` statement below `const discordClient `. I'll update my answer with the full code.

Comment: Thank you once again. No errors yet but it's taking a lot of time to start. Finger's crossed.

Comment: @FardanQureshi Maybe it helps to have the `ready` and `debug` events as well. Check my updatet answer :)